# How to create shapes on a JFreeChart line chart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to have shapes (small squares) that mark data points in the line chart that I am creating with `ChartFactory.createLineChart()`.

It should look something like this (this image was not created with JFreeChart):

[image: Line chart with square markers]

I have followed the description [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26329), however, they don't appear for me. This is what the output from my JFreeChart software looks like:

[image]

My code is:

```
JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(...);
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) lineChart.getPlot();
plot.getRenderer().setBaseShape(
    new Rectangle2D.Double(-20.0, -20.0, 40.0, 40.0));
```

I also tried using `setSeriesShape` instead of `setBaseShape` for all the series I'm plotting, it didn't make any difference either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a reference to the renderer,

```
LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
```

Invoke `setBaseShapesVisible()` to enable the shapes provided by your chosen `DrawingSupplier`.

```
renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
```

[image: image 1]

To change the appearance, pass a custom `Shape` to `setSeriesShape()` for the desired series.

```
renderer.setSeriesShape(0, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3d, -3d, 6d, 6d));
```

[image: image 2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Alas this didn't help. I tried `setBaseSeriesVisible(true)` and then also tried `setSeriesVisible` for all my series. I tried setting the shape both with `setBaseShape` and `setSeriesShape` for all series. I tried different shapes, with large sizes in case they were too small I couldn't see them. Still the same output. Is there anything else I could try? Or do you have a link to a full example working program that does this, then I could compare with my program. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you want the _shapes_ to be visible, try `setBaseShapesVisible(true)`. The `LineChartDemo[1235]` examples from the [sample charts](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) may be helpful. Because there are so many combinations, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that focuses on any remaining problem in isolation.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I confused the two methods (`setBaseSeriesVisible` and `setBaseShapesVisible`), it works now, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From JFreechart 1.5.0

```
LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) lineChart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setDefaultShapesVisible(true);
```