# How to customise line graph ( LineAndShapeRenderer ) -- set line graph colour and hide data point shapes

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

Currently, the below chart is being created using JFreeChart library.

[image]

The code to generate the above image is as follows:
However, even though, I set the plot as black color using:        `plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(2,new Color(0, 0, 0) );`
The graph always appears red.

```
            // using JFreeChart

            // create a dataset...

            DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            String series1 = "day";
            dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, "1");
            dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, "2");
            dataset.addValue(4.5, series1, "3");
            dataset.addValue(4.3, series1, "4");
            dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, "5");
            dataset.addValue(3.1, series1, "6");
            dataset.addValue(3.2, series1, "7");
            dataset.addValue(3.2, series1, "8");
            dataset.addValue(2.0, series1, "9");

            series1 = "night";
            dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, "10");
            dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, "11");
            dataset.addValue(4.5, series1, "12");
            dataset.addValue(4.3, series1, "13");
            dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, "14");
            dataset.addValue(3.1, series1, "15");




//             create the first renderer...
            final CategoryItemRenderer areaRenderer = new AreaRenderer();

            final CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot();
            plot.setDataset(dataset);
            plot.setRenderer(areaRenderer);

            //hide the gridlines
            plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
            plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);

            //hide the xAxis
            plot.setDomainAxis(new CategoryAxis(""));
            plot.getDomainAxis().setVisible(false);
            plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryMargin(0); // hide the margin between the x-axis

            //hide the yAxis
            plot.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis(""));
            plot.getRangeAxis().setVisible(false);

            // set the orientation
            plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);



//            // create the second dataset and renderer...

            series1 = "lastYear";
            plot.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis(""));
            plot.getRangeAxis().setVisible(false);

            DefaultCategoryDataset dataset2 = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            dataset2.addValue(6.0, series1, "1");
            dataset2.addValue(5.0, series1, "2");
            dataset2.addValue(5.5, series1, "3");
            dataset2.addValue(4.3, series1, "4");
            dataset2.addValue(3.0, series1, "5");
            dataset2.addValue(3.1, series1, "6");
            dataset2.addValue(5.2, series1, "7");
            dataset2.addValue(6.2, series1, "8");
            dataset2.addValue(2.0, series1, "9");
            dataset2.addValue(4.0, series1, "10");
            dataset2.addValue(4.0, series1, "11");
            dataset2.addValue(4.5, series1, "12");
            dataset2.addValue(4.3, series1, "13");
            dataset2.addValue(3.0, series1, "14");
            dataset2.addValue(5.1, series1, "15");


            final CategoryItemRenderer lineAndShapeRenderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
            plot.setDataset(2, dataset2);
            plot.setRenderer(2, lineAndShapeRenderer);

            // set the color
            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0,new Color(0, 182, 125) );
            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1,new Color(182, 224, 238));
            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(2,new Color(0, 0, 0) );


            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesShape(2, ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(5));


//            plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(2, 1);

            // change the rendering order so the primary dataset appears "behind" the
            plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);


            final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
            //hide the legend
            chart.removeLegend();
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("./report-template/chart/sample.png"), chart, 400, 300);
```

How do I change the color from red to black and how do I remove/hide the "square data points", such that it becomes a simple line graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`CategoryPlot::getRenderer`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html#getRenderer()), without an index parameter, returns the first renderer. As there there is no series with index `2`, use the renderer directly to alter its series for index `0`:

```
//plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(0, 0, 0));
lineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(0, 0, 0));
```

To hide the shapes, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73312999/230513) and noting the API change, you could use either of these on your `LineAndShapeRenderer` instance:

```
//CategoryItemRenderer areaRenderer = new AreaRenderer();
LineAndShapeRenderer lineAndShapeRenderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
…
lineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
lineAndShapeRenderer.setDefaultShapesVisible(false);
```

[image]